# How to use dynamic (growing) analytics data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I want to use Pandas for statistical analysis of analytics data. This data is not fixed, it's growing every day.

Saving the analytics data in a database just to convert it to the dataframe every time I run the analysis feels not very efficient to me as I need to run the analysis daily.

I can of course create the dataframe with first batch of data, then save the dataframe as a file. Afterwards open the file, append the new data to it and save it again.

Maybe there is better way for using Pandas with growing data? A mix between dataframe and database? Or maybe even another library?

Comment: Where's the bottleneck?

Comment: What research have you done? Like, have you considered Dask? I haven't used it myself but I know it can have dataframes that live on-disk, so that might work.

Comment: This needs a daily ingestion pipeline. This is ETL problem, not pandas problem.

Comment: @harvpan you would suggest storing data in a database and load (part of) it every time when processing it? I am  looking for an approach / pattern which is efficient and often used in cases like these.

Comment: Something like `select today's data and process it`-> `store processed data in analytics db`. You would obviously have to model your data so that you can pick it up systematically. Read on batch processing, some basic ETL and you would get it. Good luck mate :)